# Import Spotify frameworks into custom swift 3 framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, spotify

I'm trying to make a custom swift framework that wraps the Spotify frameworks

- SpotifyAuthentication.framework
- SpotifyMetadata.framework
- SpotifyAudioPlayback.framework

I import them to my custom swift framework into linked frameworks and libraries, try to build and it build fine.

When i try to import one of the frameworks with `import SpotifyMetadata`

It says `No such module 'SpotifyMetadata'`

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? :)

Thank you!

Comment: I haven't used the `Spotify` framework before. Do they includes any static library in it?

Comment: It should be a .framework file, so i think its the same in Swift

In ObjC we need to do this

`#import <SpotifyAuthentication/SpotifyAuthentication.h>
#import <SpotifyMetadata/SpotifyMetadata.h>
#import <SpotifyAudioPlayback/SpotifyAudioPlayback.h>`